# Not showing the border on top

Tags: html, css

I am using the following code with `fieldset` tag but not getting output properly.

like border top is not showing in output please give me the proper solution.

```
<div class="row" >
  <div class="tab-pane active col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12" id="saida2">
    <fieldset  style="border:1px solid #000;">
      <legend>anbsd</legend>
        <div class="row">
         <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3">
           <label class="label_text">Alíquota</label>
         </div>
         <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
           <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm">
          </div>
         </div>
     </fieldset>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: It does show fine with me: http://jsfiddle.net/VGt8a/

Comment: One border at the top is already there. I am also able to see. Do you have any css structure may be the border defined in css not correctly appear if any.

Comment: Can you please add image of expected output?

Answer (score 2):

I guess the CSS you apply via classes breaks things here. The screenshot looks OK.

You can try adding `!important` to your style: `style="border:1px solid #000 !important;"`

[image]

Comment: when iam trying this code in simple html page it will gives a same proper outout  but in my website page it not working correctly

Comment: @user3296899: as I wrote in the answer: this is because of some additional CSS rule kicking in and you have a lot: e.g. `col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3`. Did adding `!important` not help?

Comment: yes the external css is there and due to this it will be fluctuate is there having any other option like define class in style if yes so what is the css

Comment: once again.. did adding `!important` help? the CSS you have already: `border:1px solid #000` you can put it into your external CSS file but then again with `!important` or as `id` selector `#your-elem` to get highest prio when CSS is applied.

Comment: Thanks a lot guys i got a solution with proper output